# JavaScript email validation in form with python

Tags: javascript, python, forms, validation, flask

I am using the flask framework for a project I've been working on for a little while. In my messages.html page I have a form which when submitted sends it over to the python side to be stored in a text file. This is what I have so far. I can't quite understand why it is not wortking.

```
<form onsubmit="return validateMyEmail();" method="post">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Email"/ name="email" id="email" value=" {{request.form.email }}"> 
            <br>
            <textarea rows="14" id="comment" name="comment" placeholder="Comment" value=" {{request.form.comment }}"></textarea>
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

And in my script I have:

```
<script>
    function validateMyEmail() {
           var email = document.form.email.value;
           if (email.indexOf("@") < 1) 
           {
               alert("Not a valid email address");
               return false;
           } else{
                return(true);
           }
         }
</script>
```

It adds the email and message into my textfile even when I am inputting an incorrect email address. Any advice?

---

Found what the problem was. I didn't have name="form" declared in the  tag.

Comment: Are you getting the `"Not a valid email address"` alert?

Comment: @user2097159 I'm not getting any alert. It just adds to the text file and then redirects to a different page (done in python).

Comment: So from the sound of that then `if (email.indexOf("@") < 1)` is returning false ultimately dropping you into the `return(true);`